# How can I check if a hashmap contains a key of a custom class type?

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I have a hashmap whose keys are of a custom class type (class A) and I want to check whether an child class B (B extends A) appears as a key in the map.

IntelliJ gives me no warnings for the following code, but it's not going into the statement.
What could be wrong?

```
HashMap<A, Integer> map = new HashMap<A, Integer>();
map.put(new B(), 1);

if (map.containsKey(new B())) {
    System.out.println("Success!");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking if the `Map` contains a `key` of a specific instance of class `B` (not the class itself).

If you need to check if the `Map` contains a key of class `B` you can do:

```
boolean hasClass = map.keySet().stream().anyMatch(B.class::isInstance);
```

Comment: What if instead of checking if the map contains an entry with key `B`, I wanted to remove the entry (knowing it already exists)? `map.remove(new B())` will of course not work because I want to remove the `B` key that's already in the hashmap.

Comment: You should post another question. I'll try to tackle it there.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of the B() object and that new instance is not in the HashMap. Try changing the code to

```
HashMap<A, Integer> map = new HashMap<A, Integer>();
B keyToBeTested = new B();
map.put(keyToBeTested, 1);

if (map.containsKey(keyToBeTested) {
    System.out.println("Success!");
}
```